# Is it possible to generate the RTable (FlexTable) in pdf with RMarkdown?

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, flextable

I am just curious that is it possible to generate the RTable (FlexTable) in pdf with RMarkdown? I can generate it in html output but it is not working for pdf output. I google this question but there is no exact answer for it.

My code:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(ReporteRsjars)
library(ReporteRs)
library(rtable)
library(dplyr)
vanilla.table(iris)
```
````

Since it can generate in word, I assume it is possible for the pdf one.

I have tried `cat(as.html(vanilla.table(iris)))` but it is not working.

Can I friendly ask if you have any idea of it?

Answer (score 3):

This is not meant to be an answer, but only a pointer to the possible direction to solve this issue. In general, HTML output in R code chunks of an R Markdown document won't work for PDF output, just because HTML and LaTeX are totally different. However, there is an indirect way to get there, which is to take a screenshot of the HTML output and insert an image instead. This approach is used in **knitr** to deal with HTML widgets when the output format is not HTML. You can find the technical details in 
https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/plot.R (see the `html_screenshot()` function).

The basic idea is you save the HTML output as an `*.html` file, take a screenshot using the **webshot** package (which requires PhantomJS), and return the image to **knitr**. It should not be too difficult to generalize the idea to any HTML output, but I have not thought about it very carefully. This does not mean you cannot implement it by yourself, though. Below is a sketch I typed out of my mind and there is certainly a lot of details to improve:

```
insert_screenshot = function(x) {
  if (!inherits(x, c('html', 'shiny.tag'))) return()
  htmltools::save_html(x, 'temp.html')
  res = webshot::webshot('temp.html', 'my-screenshot.png')
  knitr::include_graphics(res)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the code! I will definitely work on it! I think "Screenshot the html" is a very good direction to solve this problem. Also, if this problem can be solved in this way, we can apply/extend the same method to output interactive graph into pdf issues. For example, if I want to save the results from  'rpivotTable' (one of very useful and flexible r package for pivot table), I can take the screenshot of html and return the image to knitr! Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for @Yihui,

I figured out this issue. Basically, the solution is to take the screenshot by `webshot` function and `knitr::include_graphics` to insert this png file into the pdf output.

Please try this piece of code in your markdown:

````
```{r TableJiena, out.width = "700px", out.length = "400px"}

insert_screenshot = function(x) {
  if (!inherits(x, c('html', 'shiny.tag'))) return()
  htmltools::save_html(x, 'temp.html')
  res = webshot::webshot('temp.html', 'my-screenshot.png')
  knitr::include_graphics(res)
}
insert_screenshot(htmltools::HTML(as.html(vanilla.table(head(iris)))))
```
````

If you want to get the simplified code, please try this piece of code in Markdown.

````
```{r TableJiena, out.width = "700px", out.length = "400px"}
webshot::webshot(htmltools::HTML(as.html(vanilla.table(head(iris)))), 'my-screenshot.png')
knitr::include_graphics('my-screenshot.png')
```
````

But there is a tiny issue of this solution: the solution of the PNG picture is not very high and I don't know why there are flows between each column. Also, some single lines are printed in double lines.

Can anyone figure out how to solve this minor issue of `webshot`?

Thank you!